# MySQL filter intervals within intervals of Timestamp field

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement, where I have to display employees records who has completed 5 years, 10 years, 15 years. i.e multiple of 5 years. Here the employee records should display upto 1 year i.e if employee completed 5 years it should display from 5 years upto 6 years, after 6 years it should not display the results. I have one another condition, I should get the results of the employees before 3 months from reaching 5,10,15 years
I have written a query, which showing records of all employees who has completed 5,10,15...years.
I am not able to satisy my 2nd condition i.e getting results before 3 months. Below is my query. Any suggestion could be very helpful to me

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, eji.join_date, e.last_name, e.status
  from employee as e
  JOIN employee_job_info as eji
    on e.id = eji.employee_id
 where floor(datediff('2021-12-15', eji.join_date) / 365)
 %5 = 0
   AND DATE_ADD(eji.join_date,
                INTERVAL floor(datediff('2021-12-15', eji.join_date) / 365) YEAR) BETWEEN
       '2021-09-15' AND
       DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(eji.join_date,
                         INTERVAL
                         floor(datediff('2021-12-15', eji.join_date) / 365) YEAR),
                INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Comment: Use not `DATEDIFF()` but `TIMESTAMPDIFF('year', ...)` which will produce the difference in complete years without additional operations. When you need to shift for 3 month you may add/substract according amount of months before using the function.

Comment: You made a comment on my answer post which was something related to you getting second condition satisfied etc. Did it solve your issue or there is something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of a "hack" that you can use.

Note: I'm assuming this `2021-12-15` is current date and hence I'm using `curdate()` in its place. You should too if that is the case.

Note2: From the problem statement, I get the idea that 5 years completion means between 4Y9M and 6Y, 10Y completion means 9Y9M and 11Y and so on.

Note3: From @Akina's comment -- using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` instead of `datediff`

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, eji.join_date, e.last_name, e.status
FROM employee as e
  JOIN employee_job_info as eji
    on e.id = eji.employee_id
WHERE timestampdiff('YEAR', eji.join_date, curdate()) % 5 = 0 OR
   timestampdiff('YEAR', eji.join_date, DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 3 MONTHS)) % 5 = 0
```

### Explaination of the "Hack":

1st condition is very basic. `timestampdiff` gives the differnce between `current date` and `emp joining date` in `YEARS` and that modulo 5 being 0 covers the cases where employee's time in company is between 5Y and 6Y, or from 10Y and 11Y and so on.

2nd condition adds 3 months to `current date`, hence, the difference from joining date increases by 3 months. So, practically, this mod 5 being equal to 0 covers cases where time diff is in between 4Y9M to 5Y9M, and from 9Y9M to 10Y9M, and so on.

When these 2 conditions combine with `OR`, total time into consideration covers the required 15 months for every interval of 5 years.

Comment: This query should show that, the first condition takes care of that

Comment: You do undestand the reasoning behind the hack, right?

Comment: Sorry, actually I didnt  understand the hack

Comment: As a developer, you should. If you didn't, you should have asked. I'll explain, check latest edit @Sonu

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(eji.join_date, INTERVAL floor(datediff('2021-12-15', eji.join_date) / 365) YEAR), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);`